# Watson Developer Cloud API

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson

Does the WDC API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud) use static IP addresses to access various Watson Services available through gateway.watsonplatform.net and stream.watsonplatform.net?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBM Watson cognitive services are accessible via the URI provided in the respective service credentials. They differ depending on what region, what service, and what type of service plan is used.

If you are writing a Cloud Foundry app, e.g. based on Node.js and the WDC SDK you mentioned in your question, then you can obtain the service credentials by accessing the `VCAP` environment. Code samples are in the SDK.

Comment: Nice, it's because we will no longer have support for applications using static IP to access those URL's. So, in this case, we shouldn't be worried, right?

Comment: No need to be worried.